# Using dict to run function and collecting data from function and put it in a variable

Tags: python

I am trying to change a script so it fits my needs.

The script is used to Control Husqarna Automower, and they just changed there API. With the old API and the old script i had it working. I am now trying to get the new script working as my old.

I am using Python 2.7, this is the part were i am lost.

This part of the code is Printing out the information when running it from commandpromt

```
mow = API()

mow.login("mail@mail.com", "Password")

mow.status()

print(mow.status())
```

I the get this result in the print

```
{u'storedTimestamp': 1491209355746L, u'lastLocations': [{u'latitude': 57.57327166666666, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047653333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.57335833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047641666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57335166666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047656666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57331833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047621666666666}, {u'latitude': 57.57334, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047621666666666}, {u'latitude': 57.57335166666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.04766}, {u'latitude': 57.573301666666666, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.04767}, {u'latitude': 57.57333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047643333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.57331333333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047635}, {u'latitude': 57.57328833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047595}, {u'latitude': 57.573303333333335, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047585}, {u'latitude': 57.573323333333335, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047551666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57331833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047535}, {u'latitude': 57.57332, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047641666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.573328333333336, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047673333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.57330833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047685}, {u'latitude': 57.573296666666664, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.04769}, {u'latitude': 57.57332, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047696666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57332, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047705}, {u'latitude': 57.573321666666665, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047621666666666}, {u'latitude': 57.57330666666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047618333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.57331, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047608333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.57334, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047611666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57331833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047608333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.57333333333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047621666666666}, {u'latitude': 57.5733, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047588333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.57330666666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.0476}, {u'latitude': 57.573328333333336, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047613333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.573343333333334, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047641666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57330833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047635}, {u'latitude': 57.57331, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047653333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.57330833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047693333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.573325, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047583333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.573298333333334, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047556666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.573325, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047563333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.573315, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047615}, {u'latitude': 57.57332, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047646666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57333666666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047678333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.57333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047598333333333}, {u'latitude': 57.57333333333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047586666666668}, {u'latitude': 57.573341666666664, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047573333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.573295, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047615}, {u'latitude': 57.57326666666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047636666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57326666666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047618333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.573343333333334, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047796666666667}, {u'latitude': 57.57329166666667, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.04763}, {u'latitude': 57.573303333333335, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047616666666666}, {u'latitude': 57.57331833333333, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047618333333334}, {u'latitude': 57.57331, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047631666666666}, {u'latitude': 57.57326333333334, u'gpsStatus': u'USING_GPS_MAP', u'longitude': 12.047618333333334}], u'operatingMode': u'AUTO', u'showAsDisconnected': False, u'valueFound': True, u'lastErrorCode': 0, u'lastErrorCodeTimestamp': 0, u'nextStartTimestamp': 1491350400, u'batteryPercent': 100, u'connected': True, u'mowerStatus': u'PARKED_TIMER', u'nextStartSource': u'WEEK_TIMER', u'cachedSettingsUUID': u'070b3f55-ca32-4b09-8af5-2ed49365f643'}
```

My goal is to get some of the data in to variables, so i changed that part to this

```
mow = API()

mow.login("martin@gusten.com", "mypassword")

dic_info = dict(mow.status()['mowerInfo'])
battery = dic_info.get('batteryPercent')

print battery
```

But this doesent seems to work,
when i run the script it prints

```
'mowerInfo'
```

And after that some errors generated by the script, so it seems like the mow.status never get runs?

Anyone see were I went wrong?

Comment: I don't see any `mowerInfo` as key in the dictionary, you have provided in the question which `mow.status()` returned. Could you please check that again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you're looking for is inside the main dictionary in`mow.status()`. So instead of doing `dic_info = dict(mow.status()['mowerInfo'])`, change it to `dic_info = mow.status()`, and your code should work.